# Max of count in groupby and join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hackers table

```
hacker_id   Name
  1         H1
  2         H2
  3         H3
```

Challenges table

```
 hacker_id   challenge_id
   1            C11
   1            C12
   2            C21
   1            C13
   2            C22
   3            C31
   2            C23
   2            C24
   3            C32
```

**Question: Find the maximum number count of challenges for all hacker IDs**

```
select h.hacker_id, max(count(c.challenge_id)) as max_count from Hackers h inner join Challenges c on h.hacker_id=c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id
order by h.hacker_id
```

Expected output

```
hacker_id  max_count
 2            4
```

Since hacker id 1 has 3 challenges, hacker id 2 has 4 number of challenges(maximum number of challenges), hacker id 3 has 2 number of challenges, so display 2 hacker_id and its count

Error:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` and `select top`:

```
select top (1) h.hacker_id, count(*) as cnt
from Hackers h inner join
     Challenges c
     on h.hacker_id=c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id
order by cnt desc;
```

If you want duplicates in the event of ties, use `top (1) with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties h.hacker_id, count(*) as cnt
from Hackers h inner join
     Challenges c
     on h.hacker_id=c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: Is there no way to use max and count together with group by?

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor . . . No, there is not -- at least not to do what you want.  One database does support something similar, Oracle.  But I don't recommend using the functionality there either.  That said, there are similar constructs mixing window functions and aggregation functions, and those are fine to use.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the table `Hackers` to get your expected result.
Use `COUNT()` window function:

```
select distinct top 1 with ties  
  hacker_id,
  count(*) over (partition by hacker_id) max_count
from Challenges
order by max_count desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e27fce60fd809b0f2f495f258ebe3be7).
Results:

```
> hacker_id | max_count
> --------: | --------:
>         2 |         4
```